Positive/negative connotation fallacy
This is a question about a certain kind of fallacy that for the time being I'll name (badly) the "positive/negative connotation fallacy." A person engages in this fallacy, when they refuse to say that "A is B" despite A meeting all the explicit criteria of B, when their motive for refusing to say this, which they usually do not state, is that A has positive connotations and B has negative connotations, or conversely that A has negative connotations and B has positive connotations.
Frequently, the person will invent further ad-hoc criteria to justify their claim that A is not B. But the real motive is that A and B have different positivity of connotation. It comes from a dubious, unstated assumption that what is good, is good in all cases, and what is bad, is bad in all cases, and never the two shall mix.
Take this question for example: What is the distinguishing factor between convincing and threatening? The question involves a positive-connotation word ("convincing") and a negative-connotation word ("threatening.") The dictionary definition of "convince" is:

To cause (someone) by the use of argument or evidence to believe something or to take a course of action.

By the dictionary definition, every item listed in the question is an example of (attempting to) convince someone, and the last two items are also an example of threatening them. But not a single person responding to that question even raised the idea that threatening someone could be a special case of convincing them. One has negative connotation, one has positive connotation, so everyone mutely "understands" that there must be a clear distinction drawn between them, no matter what the dictionary says!
For another example, if someone professes a hateful ideology, but does not act hatefully in accordance with it, most people are reluctant to call them a hypocrite, even though their actions meet the exact definition of hypocrisy. This reluctance comes from the fact that "not acting hatefully" has positive connotation, and "hypocrite" has negative connotation.
Has this fallacy been studied and given a (better) name?

Connotation (intension) is part of the word's meaning, placing the vague copula "is" between connoting terms without qualifications is typically misleading and declining to do so is not a fallacy even when the terms are coextensive in some abstracted sense. Natural languages rarely have "explicit criteria" to tease out denotation from connotation anyway. The reason for not equating "convincing" and "threatening" is not some assumption that "what is good, is good in all cases" but that colloquial use of "convincing", vague as it is, tends to exclude outright threats, so even denotations differ.

@Conifold Are you really objecting to the use of the word "is" as generally vague and misleading?

In the context you describe, absolutely.

The second case appears to be a generic appeal to emotion if looked at from the point of view of analyzing flaws in argument. As an underlying cognitive bias, it's a variation on the Halo Effect ("action has good traits" leads to belief "action lacks bad traits"); I don't know if it has a special name or not. You could ask on Psych SE.

You ask:

Has this fallacy been studied and given a (better) name?

Well, the example you have given, the post and response, seems a bit muddled to me, so let me respond that in the general case, the manipulation of misleading connotations and denotations is a very broad practice in rhetoric that is not necessarily a fallacy. Rhetorical strategies are often viewed through the lens of psychology, rather than logic, and abusing loaded language can happen in countless ways.
Loaded language is certainly a rhetorical technique. By invoking strong emotional associations, it is possible to persuade with claims. In fact, the framing effect is a well-known example of such a cognitive bias. In your example, by using 'threaten' as a verb as opposed to 'convince', one arouses feelings of hostility. But strictly speaking, connotation is often reflected in the specifics of the denotation in general purpose dictionaries, and what you are referring to is not a fallacy so much a question of framing. Framing is essentially the act of building a context. Let's take a look at your example:

threaten: express one's intention to harm or kill
convince: persuade to do something.

Threats are convincing acts by definition since by expressing one's intention to harm or kill, one can persuade someone to do something. But notice, the gulf in the use of the words is NOT one of connotation at all as this is a hypernym/hyponym relation. Thus, the choice of using the word with the strong negative connotation (threaten) instead of the the word with the neutral one (convince) is a fallacy ONLY IF there is another underlying fallacy. Let's imagine one.
A: You threatened me with collections!
B: No, I'm trying to convince you to avoid collections.
A: No, if you were truly trying to convince me, you wouldn't mention collections and upset me!
Here we can see an obvious flaw in reasoning. Mentioning collections and upsetting someone isn't necessarily an act with hostile intention. A threat, by definition, requires determining there is an intention to harm or kill. Simply being a messenger of imminent financial harm is not the same as the intention to cause financial harm, thus we see above, the framing of person A is potentially an example of shooting the messenger, which might be viewed as a failure in attribution. Failures of attribution are psychological, but in our imagined example, it is arguable that the fallacy, a flaw in informal logic, is tone policing. Other examples of using loaded language might have different underlying flaws in informal reason.
Thus, whether or not a fallacy is present has to be decided, not on the identification of the use of loaded language, but the specific criteria of informal fallacies. Dahmer for instance has his three, but other authors have their own approaches. The specific fallacy used in conjunction with loaded language must be determined on a case-by-case basis.
EDIT
I unearthed a term for the use of heavily skewed definitions in order to create a persuasive argument. It is known as the definist fallacy:

WP: Definist Fallacy
LogicallyFallacious.com: Definist Fallacy
PhilosophyTerms.com: Definist Fallacy
PhilPapers.org: Definist Fallacy

From the last link we have:

The definist fallacy consists of (1) defining one concept in terms of another concept with which it is not clearly synonymous, (2) as the persuasive definition fallacy, defining a concept in terms of another concept in an infelicitous way that is favorable to one's position, or (3) the insistence that a term be defined before it can be used in discussion. The simplest way to not commit any version of this fallacy is to define one's terms credibly! He/she needs to avoid using definitions that are laden with emotion or those that are idiosyncratic. That is, he/she may use more neutral and accepted definitions. If those definitions seem inadequate for his/her purposes, then he/she may argue for his/her definition.


I skimmed the other Q&A, but that seemed a bit muddled itself. I'll probably take a stab at a response myself.

You are right it is a hyponym/hypernym scenario. That's the exact scenario the fallacy is about. When it is a hyponym/hypernym scenario, but someone refuses to acknowledge that because of different positivity of connotation, they are engaging in the fallacy.

@causative Hmmm. Is there a single informal fallacy related to the selection of definitions? I'm not sure that there is, but lemme ruminate on that when I go grocery shopping.

Closely related to no true Scotsman.

@causative. Yeah, that was the first thought that popped into my mind!

So, I did some poking since the No True Scotsman didn't fit. See EDIT at the end of the post.
